# Directory index page precedes htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directoryindex

What I want is that only if my root domain is accessed meaning URI is empty, it gets rewritten without redirect, otherwise rewrite to index.php if not accessing file or folder. My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?$ /mypages/landing_page.html [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

It works as expected on some servers but on another it works only if there is no index.php file in folder. Something like directory indexing preceding htaccess rules? If I delete the index.php or rename it to index2.php and change my htaccess rules accordingly rewrite works as expected.

Any ideas what might be causing the server to behave like that?

Comment: Not sure what version of Apache you're running, but this bug sounds similar: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53929

Comment: I think you must be right. Where it works Apache is 2.2.2 and where it doesn't it is 2.4.7. Unfortunately this server is not under my control and the administrator told that the 2.4.9 version is not LTS yet and I'll have to wait for some two months. Currently I can live with that using some workarounds. Thanks for the find, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: igrynsh. It looks like a moderator deleted my original answer and converted it to a comment. I've re-posted my answer with more context this time... if you can re-accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug introduced in Apache 2.4.2 (**#53929**) that has the same symptom you're describing:

> "The issue is caused by the DirectoryIndex directive. mod_dir is not
>   respecting the result of the rewrite execution. If DirectoryIndex is
>   set to disabled, it starts working correctly."

The issue is fixed in Apache 2.4.9.

If you have a mixed environment (i.e. pre and post Apache 2.4.2 versions), this could also explain why your Rewrite is working correctly on some servers, but not others.

If upgrading is not an option, you can also workaround the issue using a conditional SetHandler (based on an env var set in your RewriteRule). This will disable DirectoryIndex for just those requests.

The bug itself (and workaround example) is documented in the following link:

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53929